# How would I present a map view a specific region on first run?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

If I want a map view to show a specific map region (which is the same each time the app launches?), how would I set that up?
Also, it is possible to prevent the user from scrolling away from this region, and also prevent the user from scrolling too far out?

Comment: Did you find a solution to preventing the user from scrolling away from the region while still being able to zoom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Specific region**

```
MKCoordinateRegion predefinedRegion;
[mapView setRegion:predefinedRegion animated:YES];
```

**2. Prevent scrolling**

```
mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

**3. Prevent zooming**

```
mapView.zoomEnabled = NO;
```

If you just want to limit the zoom level it is a bit more complicated because zooming effectively changes the region. The best way to manage this is probably by using the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol methods such as `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`.

Cheers,
Sascha

Comment: Agreed. Small addition: though I'd recommend passing `NO` for `animated` in `[mapView setRegion:animated:]` so that the app shows the region immediately instead of zooming in from the world view at launch. If the app wants to restrict someone to a certain region at all times, it doesn't make much sense to show them the whole world first and then restrict them - could be confusing to the user.

Comment: thanks. just for future reference, to set the region you do something like this (for central london):          predefinedRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.010f;predefinedRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.010f;predefinedRegion.center.latitude = 51.512f;predefinedRegion.center.longitude = -0.144f;